# shadowed parameter

Tags: c++, class, parameters, shadow

why is the second constructor shadowing the first?

```
class RC2{
    private;
        bool keyset;
    public:
        RC2(uint32_t t1 = 64){
            keyset = false;
        }

        RC2(const std::string KEY, uint32_t t1 = 64){
            RC2(t1);
            //setkey(KEY);
        }
};
```

is giving me:
`error: declaration of 'RC2 t1' shadows a parameter`

i would think that there is no way for the compiler to mess up distinguishing between these

im using codeblocks gcc with C++0x

Comment: What do you mean by "overshadow"?

Comment: what compiler are you using.  You are correct, the compiler should have no problem distinguishing between the two constructors.  On a side note, passing in a const reference to the string, not the actual string object, is a good practice.

Comment: What do you mean by overshadowing?

Comment: @Rom1: No it doesn't. Well, not with *just* an int.

Comment: @calccrypto: Can you provide some sample code where the shadowing takes place?

Comment: this is where it takes place. my real code has differnt names for the variables/parameters, but its the same thing. the real second constructor has parameters `string, uint32_t`

Comment: It's working here; gcc 4.5.2 & codeblocks 10.05. You can compile and run the program. The first constructor and the second one are not in conflict. What's the error message?

Comment: That completely changes the sense of the question - well done!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `RC2(t1);` is a local variable declaration shadowing argument `t1`, not a call to the other constructor. The following code is also valid:

```
int main(int argc,char* args[])
{
  int(a);
  a = 2;
  return a;
}
```

Note! Before C++11, there was no way to call another constructor on the same class from an constructor in C++. If you are using an old C++ version make an `Init()`-method which both constructors invoke.

Comment: there is an uppercase `T1` as a private variable, but thats it. there is no `t1` defined anywhere else except in the constructors

Comment: `RC2(const std::string KEY, uint32_t t1 = 64)` is the first declaration of `t1` and `RC2(t1)` is the second declaration (shadowing the first).

Comment: Just for future reference about "There is no way to call another constructor on the same class from an constructor in C++". This was true when written, but since C++11 this is no longer the case. Constructors can now use other constructors.

Answer (score 4):

The error is not triggered by the constructor declaration.

The error is raised on the line that declares a variable `t1` of type `RC2` in the block of the second constructor. This variable shadows the similarly named `t1` variable passed a an argument to the constructor.

I guess your intention with `RC2(t1);` was to call the other constructor, but this is not possible in C++. It will be possible in C++2011, but using another syntax.

Comment: `t1` is not a type `RC2` it is a uint32_t. and the error is marked on the second constructor

Comment: Look closer: on the first line of the body of your second constructor, you declare a variable `t1` of type `RC2`. I guess your intention was to call the other constructor, but this is not possible in C++. (It will be possible in C++2011, but using another syntax.)